# xamarin mac agent couldn't connect

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

I can't figure out why I can't get my xamarin mac agent to connect.

Here is what I'm running:
- OSX 10.11.4
- Parallels 11.2.0 with Windows 10
- Visual Studio Pro 2015

I have set up Remote Login in osx for all admins, I am using my username to connect, and I can SSH to osx from windows. I'm also on the 'Stable' update channel for xamarin on the windows and the mac sides.

Here is what I see in my xamarin log file.. thanks in advance.

```
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Messaging.State.ServerStateContext Information: 0 : [2016-05-13 11:29:17.4157] MacServer State transition from DisconnectedState to SshConnectingState on myriadsupers-MacBook-Pro.local (10.211.55.2)
Xamarin.Messaging.VisualStudio.MessagingService Information: 0 : [2016-05-13 11:29:20.3975] Starting Broker 4.0.3.214 in port 53976...
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Messaging.State.DisconnectedState Error: 0 : [2016-05-13 11:29:21.3350] Couldn't connect to myriadsupers-MacBook-Pro.local. Please try again.
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Messaging.State.DisconnectedState Information: 0 : [2016-05-13 11:29:21.4725] MacServer State transition from SshConnectingState to DisconnectedState on myriadsupers-MacBook-Pro.local (10.211.55.2)
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Messaging.State.DisconnectedState Information: 0 : [2016-05-13 11:29:21.6061] Disconnected from Mac myriadsupers-MacBook-Pro.local (10.211.55.2)
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Messaging.State.ServerStateContext Error: 0 : [2016-05-13 11:29:21.7344] Method not found: 'System.Reactive.Subjects.AsyncSubject`1<!!0> System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.GetAwaiter(System.IObservable`1<!!0>)'.
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Reactive.Subjects.AsyncSubject`1<!!0> System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.GetAwaiter(System.IObservable`1<!!0>)'.
   at System.Net.Mqtt.Client.Client.<ConnectAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Net.Mqtt.Client.Client.ConnectAsync(ClientCredentials credentials, Will will, Boolean cleanSession)
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingConnection.<ConnectAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.Ssh.SshMessagingConnection.<ConnectAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Messaging.VisualStudio.MessagingService.<ConnectAsync>d__70.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Do you have a firewall (Little Snitch?) on the OS-X side that is preventing the reverse ssh tunnel?

Comment: No, the firewall built into osx is turned off. I also tried turning off the windows firewalls for Domain networks and Private networks, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Try adding another connection in Visual Studio and do not use the default connection `.local` address, use the IP address of your Mac. And then open up `Console.app` on the OS-X, clear the contents, flip to the Windows' VM and try connecting. Watch for errors in the console, like rejected ssh connections to localhost:XXXX (ports will be randomized).

Comment: I'm seeing these two log messages:  

5/13/16 2:41:36.377 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.openssh.sshd.9B900003-0510-4416-971A-E2A793C96DED[3756]) Service exited with abnormal code: 1
5/13/16 2:41:38.440 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.openssh.sshd.2577D514-50A1-4AFD-9F61-A8A3EC73DFC1[4197]) Service exited with abnormal code: 255

Comment: 1) Make sure that you Mac and Windows are running the same Xamarin version 2) Firewall issue 3) `cat /var/log/system.log|grep -i ssh` and check for ssh authentication/**permissions**/etc. errors 4) Remove the Windows' ssh keys from from your Mac user's `.ssh/authorized_keys` 5) https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to my problem. Hope this helps other people out too.

I tried installing Visual Studio 2015 on a new vm just to see if I would be able to connect to the mac agent, and it worked. This told me that my issue was related to my windows 10 vm and not the mac side of things.

I ended up googling the MissingMethodException I had and I found [this xamarin bugzilla page](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=40250) with the exact same exception. Apparently this had to do with how Visual Studio handles plugins/extensions. I had resharper and ozcode installed on my vm, so uninstalling ozcode solved my issue. It also looks like xamarin will have a fix coming out soon to address this.

Comment: Note that this issue was solved in OzCode and in Xamarin around May 2016. Please update to the latest OzCode and the latest Xamarin and try again.

Answer (score 0):

do you try the step by step of this tutorial?

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/

and be sure your parallel windows has a valid ip address , and your mac doesn't connect to any vpn or proxy.

ok , If you check all of these and if you use parallel desktop be sure that in your parallel config of that win in Hardware - Network - choose **Shared Network**  if it doesn't work choose **bridge** mode [Parallel Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23RTo.png)

Comment: Yes, I went through all the steps in that guide and I searched for similar issues.  

One fix I tried had to do with updating the sshd_config file in osx by adding "UseDNS no" to the end of the file and restarting SSH. That didn't work for me either.  

My windows vm has a valid ip and I am not connecting to any vpn or proxy on the mac side.

Comment: This may sound silly, but I'm adding it because it happened to me, due to fatigue after a late night coding session: check your subnet masks! Verify that pings and ssh directly from the command line work. When that failed in my case I finally discovered that I had a typo in the subnet and Macs don't deal with that very well.